# Current source with pulse option

Tags: current, source

I am seeking a very fast (10nsec rise time) transistor based fixed current source that I can use with my CPU. The CPU will use the GPIO to turn on or off the current source.

This will be used to drive an LED. I have looked at several options however I am not able to find something that is really driven by an external GPIO.

I appreciate any pointers..

**Update**
I currently use a single transistor system works ok, however with temperature and variation in LEDs the current varies from unit to unit which causes problem with distance (some units meet the spec, some don't). Now I like to move to a system where the current is constant and I can use a GPIO to turn the current on or off. 10nsec rise time is desired but I will take 50nsec as well.

Voltage drop on LED is 1.9V, but I have seen up to 2.2V drop. I only have 3.3V available on the system.

Comment: 10 ns is very fast.  What is the response time of the LED?  Are you sure it can react that fast?  What are you trying to accomplish overall.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I have currently a circuit that is very fast (perhaps 20-30nsec) that drives an LED. (Simple single transistor circuit) It is part of a communication system. However with certain changes in environment my current shifts and this has an impact on the distance, it works at certain distance than stops. Now, I like to move my circuit to a constant current system where I can control the current and hence the optical output power. Speed doesn't matter that much, I can probably tolerate something as much as 50nsec.

Answer (score 4):

Since you still won't give us the obviously important information like what the digital output voltage is, what supply voltages are available, what the LED current is, and how much it drops at that current, I'm just going to make up stuff.

Here is a topology that should work:

[image]

The collector of Q1 looks like a controlled current sink when the digital signal is high.  The digital high voltage minus the B-E drop appears accross R1.  Since that is a fixed voltage, it causes a fixed current thru R1.  Due to the gain of the transistor, most of that can only come from the collector.  In this example, the voltage on R1 is about 2.6 V, so its current is 96 mA.  The LED current will be a little bit less, somewhere around 95 mA.

Note that the LED current is independent of the supply voltage as long as it is high enough.  Q1 has about 2.6 V on its emitter.  To act well as a current sink there should be at least 1 V C-E, so at least 3.6V on the collector.  In this example I assumed 1.9 V accross the LED when on, which gets us to at least 5.5 V supply.  A little more would be better so that the transistor is solidly into its current sink region.  The maximum supply voltage is only limited by the dissipation on Q1.  At 7 V supply, for example, it would dissipate about 250 mW when the LED is on.  If you are switching rapidly and using a average of 1/2 on time, then it would dissipate 125 mW at 7 V supply.

C1 is only there to speed things up a little since speed is a issue.  When the base is driven from the low to high state, C1 has to charge up.  This sends a little extra charge thru D1 at startup.  At turn off, it ensures the transistor is turned off as rapidly as possible.  The B-E junction will actually be reverse biased for a short time, which drains the minority carriers out of the base region quickly.  The value I show for C1 is a very rough guess.  There are too many unknowns to predict the requirements accurately.  The C1 value is best found by starting with a vaguely plausible value as shown, then find the right value by experimentation while watching the collector voltage on a scope.

Comment: Thanks Olin, great and ultra simple answer. I unfortunately only have 3.3V available. Can I use a simple voltage divider in front of the base of the transistor to achieve 3.3V compatibly?

Comment: @Ktc: A voltage divider could work and still allow a fixed current sink as long as R1 is adjusted to the new voltage accordingly.  However, since you are interested in speed I would worry about it slowing down the edges.  Carefully tuning it with capacitors may help.  The other problem is that you want the B-E drop of Q1 to be a small portion of the base to ground voltage when the current sink is on.  The B-E drop can change over temperature and other parameters, which is why you want most of the voltage accross R1.  Maybe you can connect to the unregulated supply used to make the 3.3V?

Comment: trimmer caps: http://search.digikey.com/ca/en/cat/capacitors/trimmers-variable/131670

Comment: Make sure the referenced GPIO drive impedance and properly terminated rise time is known. A buffer may be needed, taking transistor base capacitance (impedance with <2ns edges) into account, especially if also using it for collector (current) source.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more abstract, but you may find it of use:

http://ronja.twibright.com/

They have schematics for communications systems (which from what I can tell is what you're looking at) and they use LEDs.

Comment: good resource but way to complex for what I am aspiring to accomplish.